# 自動補完プラグインcoq_nvimをinit.luaファイルで有効化する方法が知りたい。

Tags: lua, neovim

提示コードですが以下の`Github`のプラグインを`nvim`上で使いたいのですが`readme`に説明がなくて有効化方法がわかりません。とりえず`Packer`を使ってダウンロードはしたのですが`init.lua`ファイルにどうやって書き込んだらいいのかわかりません。提示のエラーは`--2`のコードです。`Gtihub`の`インストール`部参照

###### エラーログ

```
/home/shigurechan/.config/nvim/init.lua の処理中にエラーが検出されました:
E5113: Error while calling lua chunk: /home/shigurechan/.config/nvim/init.lua:14: attempt to call field 'setup' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
        /home/shigurechan/.config/nvim/init.lua:14: in main chunk
```

Github: https://github.com/ms-jpq/coq_nvim
参考サイト：https://github.com/ms-jpq/coq_nvim/issues/11

###### init.lua

```lua
--require("coq").setup() --1
--require("coq").setup({}) --2
--require("coq").setup(); --3
```

Comment: [Install](https://github.com/ms-jpq/coq_nvim#install) や参照している Issue を見る限り、プラグインマネージャの vim-plug や vundle の利用を推奨しているようです。

Comment: これはもう別のプラグインを使ったほうがいいのでしょうか？